Disable first 20 items from showing up in Choice DataCard
I've been trying to change a choice datacard to appear like a text input but function like a choice datacard (when a user enter a text, the options containing similar string should show up). I hid the chevron that basically shows the dropdown containing the first 20 choices in my column but how do I disable it from showing those? Thank you in advanced!

Here is what I currently have for the Items property of the combobox:
Filter('Order Tracker - Test', StartsWith(Branch.Label, DataCardValue7.SearchText))


How many choice options you have in column settings? Is there anything common/unique in the choice options you want to hide, like hide the options which starts with 00, etc.?
